# Classic and Extended MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

- **In the classic MVC:**

[image]

The setup mechanism is the following:

1. Instantiate model
2. Instantiate view (Has reference to a controller, initially null)
3. Instantiate controller with references to both (Controller registers with view, so view now has a (non-null) reference to controller)

The question is why in the second step the view should have reference to the controller (i think the controller having a reference to the view is enough) ?

- **In the Extended MVC:**

[image]

The setup mechanism is the following:

1. Instantiate model (Has reference to view, initially null)
2. Instantiate view with reference to model (View registers with model)
3. Instantiate controller with references to both (Controller registers with view)

The question is why in the the first step the model should have a reference to the view (what i know is that the model shouldn't know anything about the views, and the pattern Observer should be used in this case) ?

[Here is the source link.](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~rountev/421/lectures/lecture23.pdf)

Thanks for advance.

Comment: That is **not** "classical MVC".

Comment: @tereško I found the names in the document which is linked with the question description. Can you give the correct names please ?

Comment: For "classical mvc" please see [this publication](http://www.itu.dk/courses/VOP/E2005/VOP2005E/8_mvc_krasner_and_pope.pdf). I have no idea what "extended mvc" is, but there is a thing that is commonly referred to as "web mvc", or [model 2 mvc](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076557/java-web-development/understanding-javaserver-pages-model-2-architecture.html), which is basically the classical one, but without the observers and a requirement for a persistent model (better suited for request-response nature of web sites).

Comment: ... oh, and then there is Ruby on Rails, which used "mvc" as marketing term while having nothing in common with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for both questions is the same. Your diagram is very abstract and you are totally right there should be no direct reference in both cases. You can either reference by a well defined interface(duck typing) or by subscribing to events happing at the observable object.

Look at your observer example. According to it, the only thing an observable knows about its observer is the fact that they respond to the `notify` method. So technically there is actually a circular reference between the two, but in case of the reference from the observable(model) to the observer(view), it's a week one.

Same applies for the first case. The View does not directly know the controller. But the controller has to be notified on UI events(e.g button clicked) and respond to them. This is often done by having the controller register to events happening in the view. But technically the view will maintain a list of its event responders. So there is actually a reference, but again a weak one. It will not stop you from reusing the same view with another controller.

So, your concerns are right, circular dependencies are a smell. But on the low technical level they are required and in order to achieve lose coupling you just have to make one side of them weak, which will make the dependency exchangeable

Comment: So theoretically circular references are forbidden but technical problems can force them to exist inside code.

Comment: They are not forbidden. It's just how your programn considers them. An observable will always maintain an Array of it's observers. Technically it is a reference. But it sticks strictly to the interface of having a notify method. It could be anything, that just has a notify method on it. In some languages like Java there is even a strict interface concept. An Observer class will have to declare that it's implementing the observer intetface otherwise it cannot be registered